# Mock databases function from drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I want to create a phpunit test from the following code, but I'm not even sure if it worth it, because the code contains db_update and db_query functions, so, those are database functions and I don't know if it make sense create a test for this, because I don't know if should assume drupal code is working fine.

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\forum_innovation\Forum;

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ldcontreras
 * Date: 30/05/18
 * Time: 18:26
 */
class ForumCounter implements ForumInterface {


    public static function setForumCounter($forum, $uid) {
        $counterState = db_update('forum_counter_states')
            ->fields(array(
                'state' => 'read',
            ))
            ->condition('uid', $uid)
            ->condition('tid', $forum)
            ->execute();

        return $counterState;

    }

    public static function getForumNotification($forum, $uid) {
        $unReadNotifications =
            db_query('SELECT count(*) as counter 
                                FROM {forum_counter_states} as f WHERE f.uid = :uid AND f.state = :state AND f.tid = :forum',
                                array(
                                    ':uid' => $uid,
                                    ':forum' => $forum,
                                    ':state' => 'unread'
                                )
            )->fetchAll();

        return $unReadNotifications[0]->counter;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a test like this, but I need some help and clarification:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ldcontreras
 * Date: 8/06/18
 * Time: 10:02
 */

namespace Drupal\forum_innovation\Forum;


class ForumCounterTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function TestSetForumCounter() {

        $db_query = $this->getMock('db_update',  array('fields', 'condition', 'execute'));

        $db_query->expects($this->once())->method('fields')->with($this->equalTo(array(':uid' => 3024));

        $db_query->expects($this->once())->method('condition')->with($this->equalTo(array(':uid' => 3024)));

        $db_query->expects($this->once())->method('condition')->with($this->equalTo(
            array(':tid' => 83))->will(
            $this->returnCallback('callback'));



    }



}
```

Thanks!